# Parent Unordered List Element Won't Link in Sidebar Menu

Tags: list, parent-child

If you visit this page you will find that you cannot click the parent page 'Agriculture' in the sidebar menu:
http://macroairfans.com/industries/agriculture/equine/

You can click any of the other children elements but the parent element doesn't link.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Raleigh